# Store: Specific channel for exp:store_search doesn't work?

Tags: expresso-store, channel-entries

I'm banging my head on this and new to EE as a cms - perhaps there's an obvious answer

I have the latest Store and EE2.10.x and I have several channels dedicated to Store items. I want to show all contents from just one channel:

```
{exp:store:search orderby="title" sort="asc" limit="10"}
  {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    {title}
  {/exp:store:product}
{/exp:store:search}
```

This looks at all channels for content produces a title, as I understand it should from the docs as it's a wrapper for *{exp:channel:entries}*.

But I get no results if I try to get Store to show only 1 channel:

```
{exp:store:search orderby="title" sort="asc" limit="10" channel="channel3"}
  {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    {title}
  {/exp:store:product}
{/exp:store:search}
```

Since I only need a item listing, I thought I'd try a standard {exp:channel:entries} but I get no listings at all either? Event the titles aren't being show, which is really confusing.

Am I missing something? Shouldn't Store or EE be able to list items in a specific channel?

Comment: Try removing the `exp:store:product` tag pair using the channel entries loop with your channel in question. If you are still not getting the titles to display from that you need to make sure that you channel short name is indeed channel3. Also by default EE only shows entries with a status of open so if you are using custom statuses you will need to add either `status="not closed"` or `status="open|custom|status"` with a  pipe character between any status you want to show. Once you have the channel entries loop working as expected you should be able to change it to the store search tag

Comment: Store and EE both allow to filter by a particular channel by using the `channel=""` parameter. Also if you are not allowing the user to add items to the cart from this view you can access a few things like price like this `{exp:channel:entries}{title}{product:price}{/exp:channel:entries} where product is the custom field name for the store field.

Comment: It is also a good idea to add `{if no_results}There are no results{/if}` within your channel entries or store search tags just to rule that.

Comment: Removed, and no - none of this is working - even the suggested:

'{exp:channel:entries channel="channel1"}{title}{/exp:channel:entries}'

yields an empty template. I can see entries from non-Store channels, but nothing from a Store-equipped channel

Comment: Remove the channel limitation then in your template add {title}-{channel_short_name} between your channel entries tags. This should give you the correct short names you can use in the channel parameter

Comment: The short name is correct, but it did identify a different issue; some of the channel content isn't resolving. I can see open items, but they're not being listed. If I add a new item, the new item **is seen**, just not the old items. I was testing on a couple channels which have this issue (seems like a database thing - channels preferences are the same, as are user permissions).

So the problem is elsewhere than the channels (..whew)